# Can we add tags in any spreadsheet software like we can in Notion?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets, tags, iwork-numbers

I’m working on long tables (like a database or repository, no mathematical function) and

1. I need to refer a few cells in another sheet
2. And also use some tags for each row.
   I know in Notion, you can refer a cell into another cell and also can create pretty tags.

Can we do that in any spreadsheet software like Microsoft excel, Google sheets or Apple numbers? I don’t want to use Notion and Google sheet if possible because I don’t want the data on cloud.

Comment: You can "link" to other sheets and cells in Excel. Just right-click on a cell and select "link" to create your link.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Excel does not have a built-in tagging capability. Your options:

1. Use a number of columns and just type your tags in, one per cell. Excel will remember values in a column and offer them up as auto-complete suggestions, but it only work per column - so keep tags of a certain type or category in a single column.
2. Enter all tags in a single column separated by commas. This allows for any number of tags, but you lose the auto-complete functionality somewhat.
3. Google for "implementing tags in Excel". There are a few nice videos by Rockstar Excel as well as HowtoExcel.net on doing exactly this. Ignore most results for "Smart Tags" i.e. Excel's little popup menus when you paste into a cell etc.

As for making it "pretty", you could (for option 1) insert a rounded corner rectangle, set it ~60% transparent and set the fill and border colour as you like. Move and size it inside a cell, with the cell value itself as the tag name (visible through the transparent shape).By default the shape will move and copy with the cell, so you can easily copy and paste the tag from the header row. E.g.:

[image]